# Spring Data JPA compilation error when upgrading Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE to 2.0.0.M4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPA repository:

```
public interface ProductRepositoryJPA extends CrudRepository<Product,String>,
                           PagingAndSortingRepository<Product,String> {

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(value="EVERYTHING", type= EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Product findOne(String id);


}
```

If I try and compile with spring-boot 2.0.0.M4, I encounter the following error:

```
ProductRepositoryJPA.java:[21,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

The code compiles fine if I use Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

It also compiles fine if I remove the @Override annotation and keep Spring Boot at version  2.0.0.M3 .

Here is my dependency tree for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3:

```
-- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ example-load ---
[INFO] com.example.product-load:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.M4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.M4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.0.RC4:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.0.RC4:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.0.RC3:compile
```

and my dependency tree for Spring-Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.6.RELEASE:compile
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out my "overriding" method , to allow the build to compile with Spring-Boot-2.0.0.M4 - I realized the findOne(T id) is no longer supported in spring-data-commons 2.0.0. Seemingly it has been replaced with the findById(T id) method.